# present simple + recently

Tags: grammar, present-tense, perfect-constructions

Today I got into argument with my colleague about the answer of below question.

She claims both are possible but choice **2** is the better one saying that "economics is a branch of science and if we are talking about its description, Present Simple is the answer".

It is such an easy question that I didn't put it on English Language & Usage stack. The question is below.

> There have been economies since the dawn of civilization, but as a field of study, economics **[...]** only recently.
>
> 1) **has developed**
>
> 2) **develops**

Can someone explain why her logic is wrong? I tried but it was futile. Maybe if she can see others then she might learn something. (Answer sheet is also saying 1).

If somebody says "I am busy recently/lately" it feels like saying "I am busy two days ago". It just does not makes sense. Recently/lately means near past. I am busy these days is fine however.

Comment: It is not clear what the question is. Does answer (1) give two choices for the first "..." and answer (2) give two choices for the second "..." ?

Comment: My apologies. This is just a fill in the blanks question. The first blank "..." is "have been" for both choices. The second blank however either "has developed" or "develops".

Comment: In that case, option 1 is the answer. "There **have been** economies since the dawn of civilization, but as a field of study, economics **has developed** only recently."

Comment: If you can explain your thought process to that question, and why her logic is wrong, I would really appreciate.

Comment: The "recently" is in the past, but "develops" is in the present - wrong tense.

Comment: I do understand what you're asking, but I agree that you could make it clearer. Why include that first blank in both sentences if there's no dispute about what is to fill it? Also, I think you're seeking confirmation that "has developed" is right and "develops" is wrong, but you don't say so explicitly. Finally, the "I am busy lately/recently" example is so different that including it is probably counterproductive. (Many native speakers who have been busy recently and are still busy *would* in fact say something like "I'm so busy lately that I don't know whether I'm coming or going.")

Comment: @Nanigashi as a native speaker I would not say "I am so busy lately." I would say "I've been so busy lately." Using the present tense I would say "I am so busy these days."

Comment: @Weather Vane, yes, that's what I would say, too, but that doesn't change the fact that *many native speakers* would use the present tense in a sentence like that – which is not at all true of the sentence the OP is actually interested in.

Comment: @Nanigashi native speakers may use all manner of incorrect tenses. Why do you muddy the water by mentioning something that is grammatically incorrect?

Comment: I will edit the question for clarity. I am also aware of incorrect usages. I included I am busy recently" to explain how the usage is with present simple. I am a native as well. And yes I am looking for a confirmation. I know being a native does not make one a language expert automatically.

Comment: I think  her problem comes from learning recently, lately and these days having exact similar meanings as well as not considering their usage.

Comment: @Weather Vane, I believe it can be useful to distinguish between usages that virtually no native speaker would accept and those that many would accept – and indeed, that it’s in failing to do so that we risk “muddying the water” for the learners we are trying to help. It’s clear you have a different opinion about this, and that’s fine.

Comment: Note that the present is also acceptable, but you would need to restate the sentence slightly: *but as a [recent] field of study, economics* ***is still developing***.

Answer (score 2):

Economics as a field of study, is young but not new. Therefore it is plain wrong to speak of its development in the present tense.

Therefore, the only good variant is:

> There have been economies since the dawn of civilization, but as a field of study, economics **has developed** only recently.

Comment: Thank you. She insists that it is talking about its general description and I think she is missing a few screws in the head.

Comment: I am not a mechanical repair man, so I know nothing about screws - in the head or anywhere else :D

Comment: or omit the 'has' *There have been economies since the dawn of civilization, but as a field of study, economics **developed** only recently*